# How do the slicing effects work in the Fruit Ninja game?

Tags: iphone, slice

Does anybody know how slicing effects work in the Fruit Ninja game?

[image: screenshot of Fruit Ninja game]

Or any other way to achieve a similar effect?

How to get that all swipe point at how to draw line on that 
please help ....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i draw the many  lines to give slicing effect and removed points simultaneously from that mutable array where i put the point to draw line

code:-

```
-(void)init
    {
     [self checkAllArray];
     [self schedule:@selector(removePoints:) interval:0.0001f];
    }
-(void)checkAllArray
{
    if (naughtytoucharray==NULL)
        naughtytoucharray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    else
    {
        [naughtytoucharray release];
        naughtytoucharray=nil;
        naughtytoucharray=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
}

-(void)draw
{
    glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
    glColor4ub(255, 255, 255, 255); //line color 
    //glLineWidth(2.5f);
    for(int i = 0; i < [naughtytoucharray count]; i+=2)
    {
        CGPoint start = CGPointFromString([naughtytoucharray objectAtIndex:i]);
        CGPoint end = CGPointFromString([naughtytoucharray objectAtIndex:i+1]);
                ccDrawLine(start, end); // line 1
        ccDrawLine(ccp(start.x-2,start.y-2),ccp(end.x-2,end.y-2));// line 2
        ccDrawLine(ccp(start.x-4,start.y-4),ccp(end.x-4,end.y-4));// line 3
        ccDrawLine(ccp(start.x-6,start.y-6),ccp(end.x-6,end.y-6));// line 4
        ccDrawLine(ccp(start.x-8,start.y-8),ccp(end.x-8,end.y-8));// line 5
    }
}

- (void)ccTouchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event 
{
    CGPoint new_location = [touch locationInView: [touch view]];
    new_location = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:new_location];
    CGPoint oldTouchLocation = [touch previousLocationInView:touch.view];
    oldTouchLocation = [[CCDirector sharedDirector] convertToGL:oldTouchLocation];
    [naughtytoucharray addObject:NSStringFromCGPoint(new_location)];
    [naughtytoucharray addObject:NSStringFromCGPoint(oldTouchLocation)];
}

-(void)removePoints:(ccTime *)tm
{
    if ([naughtytoucharray count]>0)
    {
        [naughtytoucharray removeObjectAtIndex:0];
    }
}

-(void)dealloc
{
    //NSLog(@"deallocing lightning\n");
    [self removeAllChildrenWithCleanup:YES];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You get several control points in the screen space. Then interpolate them and build several polygons that lie along that curve. You can use fragment shaders to draw the border or texturing (but I think it would be harder).